# What was the point of Sakura's bed doll being dressed as Sakura is in her dream?

Tags: cardcaptor-sakura

In episode 44, Sakura wakes up and describes her recurring dream of the Final Judgement. She also notices that the Sakura shaped doll that she keeps by her bed is dressed exactly like she is in the dream. The very same doll appears since very early in the series, and IIRC it is said that it was sewed by Tomoyo.

This element is not elaborated further upon in the episode nor in the following episodes.

So what is that statement's purpose in the story?